# retrieving radio button value if name is from database(lopped)

Tags: javascript, php

i am making a simple quiz

the code below is my code for echoing the questions in the database
i used while loop to output the values in the database

i used the q_question for the name of each radio button, because if i put (sample : name="question" which is fixed, when it loop i am only available to pick 1 radio button even if theres 2 or more questions  )

```
<?php

$tbl_name2="a_quiz"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE q_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr style='overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;'>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>Question:</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen" style="max-width: 1000px;"><?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>A</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="a"><?php echo $rows['a'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>B</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="b"><?php echo $rows['b'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>C</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="c"><?php echo $rows['c'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><strong>D</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen">:</td>
<td bgcolor="lightgreen"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $rows['q_question'] ?>" value="d"><?php echo $rows['d'] ?></td>
</tr>

</table></td>
</tr>
<hr>
</table><br>
<?php
}
?>
```

my problem is i cannot get the values of the radio button
im trying $my_answer=$_POST['$q_question'];(and i think this is so wrong) + submit button

help me get the values of the radio button, using php
but if you got idea using javascript etc.. im happy to see it

Comment: I think you mean `$my_answer=$_POST[$q_question];` where `$q_question` is the variable holding the name of the question from the database. You had `'` around it which would have treated it as a literal string.

Comment: $my_answer=$_POST[$q_question]; i think this is correct, should i declare the $rows['q_question'] first to $_question? or i can do this $my_answer=$_POST[$rows['q_question']]; ??

Comment: Both would work though I find to keep your code clean, I would do your first suggestion. So something like `$questionName = $rows['q_question']; $myAnswer = $_POST[$questionName];`

Comment: should i put that inside the loop or when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Because you don't know the question names without looping over rows in the DB, it will need to be inside a loop of the records.